# How to add an image in CGridview

Tags: gridview, yii

This is my index for the gridview of the table:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'tblvehicleimagegrid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(

    'serial_no',
    array(
      'name'  =>'image',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=> CHtml::image(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')."/images/originals/images.jpg"),

    ),

    'line_no',
..........
.........
```

Comes with an error

[image]

Need some help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7163-cgridview-not-rendering-image/).

If you write the code as bettor did on the Yii forums:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(

            array(
              'name'=>'Flag',
                'type'=>'image',
                'value'=>'CHtml::image("images/flags/".$data->country.".gif", "country")',
            ),

    ),
));
```

Then you'll end up with this:

```
<img alt="" src="<img src="images/flags/England.gif" alt="country" />"/>
```

Note the incompatible elements?

In other words, you're going to need to set the 'type' in your column declaration to 'html,' so that CGridView knows to look for HTML, which is what CHTML::image is going to give you.

edit:

I know the Yii docs can be a little unclear, but if you look at the code, it'll often make sense. In this case, the docs for [CHTML::image()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#image-detail) do tell us that it returns an image tag, specifically.

Comment: hm...i totally removed 'CHtml::image' part; it's working now. Thanx for the guideline though.. only if i could knew how to solve it using
CHtml::image; it would be an addition.

also it's important to add the single quote around the line just like @naveen goyal mentioned

Answer (score 1):

add single quote in value like this...

```
'value'=> 
'CHtml::image(Yii::getPathOfAlias("webroot")."/images/originals/images.jpg")',
```