# How can I add somthing value in cell with yii cgridview?

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I need add name and date and user image in one cell. I tried code below and some another way. But I got only errors

```
'columns'=>array(
   array('name'=>'sender', 'value'=> '"' . $model[key?]->name . $model[key?]->date .'"'),
)
```

Is  this task perhaps solve? Maybe do I need use another widget or create my own widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a CGridView `value` expression `$data` refers to the current object/array in the `dataProvider`. Therefore to get the attributes of the current object:

```
'columns'=>array(
     array(
          'name'=>'sender',
          'type'=>'raw', //or html
          'value'=> '$data->name ." ". $data->date." ".CHtml::image($data->image_src)'
     ),
)
```

Comment: Good, but not full decision. How add there image? I found way but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879217/how-to-add-an-image-in-cgridview in may happening it don't work...

Comment: You can add any expression you want (even html) code to the value expression as long as you quote it properly, as shown above.

Comment: great, I need added type html. Thanks